# BadCredentialsException: Kerberos validation not succesfull

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-security, kerberos, spnego

I would like to perform authentification with SPNEGO. I use:

- spring-core-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
- spring-security-core-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
- spring-security-kerberos-core-1.0.0.M2.jar
- package codec from spring
  core security 3.0.7 (https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SES-98)
- tomcat

My Config file looks like the following. When I try to authentificate  with the above libraries I got the following exception.

Had someone the same problem and handled it?

Config file (taken from spring security kerberos example):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- This configuration uses SPNEGO by default, but one could also use a form if he directly goes to /login.html -->
    <sec:http entry-point-ref="spnegoEntryPoint" use-expressions="true">
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/secure/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <sec:custom-filter ref="spnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter"
            position="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <sec:form-login login-page="/login.html" default-target-url="/secure/index.jsp"/>
    </sec:http>

    <bean id="spnegoEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.web.SpnegoEntryPoint" />

    <bean id="spnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.web.SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    </bean>

    <sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <sec:authentication-provider ref="kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider" /> <!-- Used with SPNEGO -->
        <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="dummyUserDetailsService"/> <!-- Used with form login -->
    </sec:authentication-manager>



    <bean id="kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider"
        class="org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="ticketValidator">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator">
                <property name="servicePrincipal" value="HTTP/xxx.xx.xx.xx@XX-XXX.XXX.XX" />
                <!-- Setting keyTabLocation to a classpath resource will most likely not work in a Java EE application Server -->
                <!-- See the Javadoc for more information on that -->
                <property name="keyTabLocation" value="file:/home/xxxxx/conf/krb5/krb5.keytab" />
                <property name="debug" value="true" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="userDetailsService" ref="dummyUserDetailsService" />
    </bean>

    <!-- This bean definition enables a very detailed Kerberos logging -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.GlobalSunJaasKerberosConfig">
        <property name="debug" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <!--
        Just returns the User authenticated by Kerberos and gives him the
        ROLE_USER
    -->

    <bean id="dummyUserDetailsService"
        class="org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.sample.DummyUserDetailsService" />

</beans>
```

Exception which I got:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Kerberos validation not succesfull
        at org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.validateTicket(SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.java:69)
        at org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider.java:86)
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
        at org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.web.SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:131)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve.invoke(JvmRouteBinderValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve.invoke(ReplicationValve.java:333)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: GSSException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level: Invalid argument (400) - Cannot find key of appropriate
type to decrypt AP REP - RC4 with HMAC)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.validateTicket(SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.java:67)
        ... 29 more
Caused by: GSSException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level: Invalid argument (400) - Cannot find key of appropriate type to decrypt AP REP - RC4 with HMAC)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.acceptSecContext(Krb5Context.java:778)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:342)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:285)
        at sun.security.jgss.spnego.SpNegoContext.GSS_acceptSecContext(SpNegoContext.java:871)
        at sun.security.jgss.spnego.SpNegoContext.acceptSecContext(SpNegoContext.java:544)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:342)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:285)
        at org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator$KerberosValidateAction.run(SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.java:146)
        at org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator$KerberosValidateAction.run(SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.java:136)
        ... 32 more
Caused by: KrbException: Invalid argument (400) - Cannot find key of appropriate type to decrypt AP REP - RC4 with HMAC
        at sun.security.krb5.KrbApReq.authenticate(KrbApReq.java:273)
        at sun.security.krb5.KrbApReq.<init>(KrbApReq.java:144)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.InitSecContextToken.<init>(InitSecContextToken.java:108)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.acceptSecContext(Krb5Context.java:761)
        ... 40 more
```

Comment: Hmm, seems like bug to me. Try filling a ticket at [Spring Security's JIRA](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC).

Comment: This looks like a kerberos configuration issue. Check your keytab file contains a key of the correct type (23 for rc4-hmac).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem.
Spring-security-kerbos requires path to keytab file as "Resource String" (details: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/resources.html).
When I set path as "file:/home/xxxxx/conf/krb5/krb5.keytab" then application runs but I think that it can't open the file later and Kerberos cant load any key. Unfortunately Log from Kerberos is not so clear.

When I set path as "/home/xxxxx/conf/krb5/krb5.keytab" I got the following exception

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ServletContext resource [/home/xxxxx/conf/krb5/krb5.keytab] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
```

Solution for this issue can be the fix in the file SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.java:

```
private String keyTabLocation;

LoginConfig loginConfig = new LoginConfig(keyTabLocation, servicePrincipal, debug);
```

instead of:

```
private Resource keyTabLocation;

LoginConfig loginConfig = new LoginConfig(keyTabLocation.getURL().toExternalForm(), servicePrincipal, debug);
```

With this fix everything works. We can set path to file in format "/home/xxxxx/conf/krb5/krb5.keytab"

If someone knows more details about it, please write it here.

Comment: How you able to create instance of LoginConfig class because it's private inner class of SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator ? Also I am facing similar issue ('Checksum failed') and posted my query on this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57726513/spring-boot-ldap-ad-kerberos-sso-krbcryptoexception-checksum-failed) could please check and found any suggestion on it ?

Comment: copy just SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator to your project and change the code

Answer (score -1):

At least Java 7 is not (or, my version is not) able to handle the "file:" prefix: [See this link](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=2221392). I had to make the same modification to Spring sources as you did. Thanks, this was helpful. Wasted half a week on trying different configurations.

Comment: This doesn't seem like an answer to the question. You should have posted it as a comment on the other answer.